# Запрос sql выборка сообщений

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица messageprivate со структурой:

```
 id | from_user | to_user | message | date | status |
```

в ней хранятся сообщения. Из структуры ясно, что from_user - это пользователь который написал сообщение, to_user - кому он это написал, message - собственно само сообщение, date - когда написал и status - прочитано оно или нет, по умолчанию это поле равно 0, а когда пользователь которому оно было написано его читает оно меняется на 1.

Необходимо написать sql запрос который выведет сообщения сгруппированные типа как в контакте когда заходим в раздел сообщения - т.е. видим перечень переписок с каждым пользователем, а именно по последнему сообщению от каждого пользователя и количество непрочитанных сообщений.

Изначально нам известен наш id - т.е. когда мы пишем кому-то то наш id попадает в поле from_user, а когда нам кто-то пишет то наш id попадает в поле to_user.

3 часа уже под хвост...

Спасибо!

Comment: `select count(1) as count_unreaded from messageprivate where status = 0 and to_user = OUR_USER_IDENTIFICATOR group by from_user` ?   лучше бы на http://sqlfiddle.com/ тестовые данные выложили

Comment: Нет... Непрочитанных сообщений от каждого пользователя может быть много, а вывести нужно только последнее от каждого пользователя и количество этих не прочитанных сообщений...

Comment: Формулировка неполна. 1) Какое сообщение выводить, если последний пост был: от текущего юзера? от его собеседника? 2) Тип полей from_user и to_user - числовой? GUID? текстовая хрень?

Comment: 1) Выводить именно последнее - если последнее было от текущего - значит от текущего и выводить, если от собеседника - значит от собеседника выводить. 2) числовой. Дальше не понял Вас...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select if(from_user=@user,to_user,from_user) recipient,
       max(date) last_date,
       substr(max(concat(date,message)),20) last_msg,
       sum(status=0) not_seen
  from messageprivate
 where from_user=@user or to_user=@user
 group by recipient
```

`@user` это наш пользователь для которого выборка

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0855b/1)

Comment: *ушел дальше учиться писать запросы*. Однозначно плюс, с получением последнего сообщения хитро, хитро :)

Comment: Только status = 0 нужно посчитать там где сообщение пришло нашему пользователю, т.е. там где to_user = @user

Comment: @Александр `sum(status=0 and to_user=@user)` любая логическая конструкция в MySQL на выходе дает 0 или 1

Comment: Браво! Спасибо!

Comment: Не... Выводит не последнее сообщение... поле date - типа datetime. И еще не пойму что значит число 20 в функции substr, для чего оно там нудно?

Comment: @Александр Какое значение дает у вас `select length(date) from messageprivate` ? у меня для datetime оно дает 19, т.е. длину даты в символьном виде. Вот со следующего, 20 символа и расположено сообщение. И дата в символьном виде (можно проверить `concat(date,'')`) у меня в формате `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` при сортировке такой строки порядок записей верный и max должно дать последнее значение. Если у вас получается не последнее сообщение - то возможно у вас что то не так с форматом даты и ее тогда надо руками привести к нормально сортируемому формату

Comment: У меня тоже дает 19... формат даты как я написал выше datetime... В символьном виде точно так же YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS... Но выводит первое сообщение, а не последнее...

Comment: @Александр Эммм ... вы там точно min вместо max не написали ? По крайней мере другого объяснения такого поведения мне в голову не приходит ...

Comment: Меняю max на min и наоборот - ничего не происходит... Все врем первое сообщение....

Comment: @Александр И строку один к одному взяли ... сначала собираем значение concat, потом от него целиком берем max и потом вырезаем сообщение обратно ... В примере на sqlfiddle же правильные сообщения выбирает ... сделали бы пример на fiddle который бы демонстрировал неверное поведение ...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57784/discussion-between--and-mike).

Comment: Все правильно! Просто смотреть нужно внимательней) Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

На данных не тестил, но алгоритм примерно такой:

- берем все отправленные сообщения, составляем переписку с людьми, которым мы писали. Присоединяем последнее сообщение, чтобы показывалось, как в переписке в вк во вкладке "Мои сообщения"
- делаем то же самое, только со входящими сообщениями от пользователей
- объединяем все в одну таблицу и сортируем по времени (для удобства у меня название таблицы `mp` вместо `messageprivate`)

---

```
select *
from (
    select to_user,
        mp1.message,
        mp1.date,
        m1.count_sent_unread
    from
    /* в подзапросе отправленные сообщения от нас с макс датой и количеством непрочитанных */
          (select from_user, to_user,
              max(date) as max_sent_date,
              sum(if(status = 0, 1, 0)) as count_send_unread
           from mp
           where from_user = 100
           group by from_user, to_user
           ) m1
      join /* чтобы получить последнее сообщение в переписке */
          mp1 ON m1.from_user = mp1.from_user and m1.to_user = mp1.to_user and m1.max_sent_date = mp1.date

    UNION /* объединяем то же самое, только со входящими сообщениями */

    select from_user,
        mp2.message,
        mp2.date,
        m2.count_receive_unread
    from
    /* в подзапросе входящие сообщения с макс датой и количеством непрочитанных */
          (select from_user, to_user,
              max(date) as max_receive_date,
              sum(if(status = 0, 1, 0)) as count_send_unread
           from mp
           where to_user = 100
           group by from_user, to_user
           ) m2
      join mp2 ON m2.from_user = mp2.from_user and m2.to_user = mp2.to_user and m2.max_sent_date = mp2.date) mes
order by date desc
```

Comment: Что-то слишком длинно... плюс из каждого диалога будут по 2 сообщения попадать.

Comment: @Akina были бы в MySQL оконные функции, можно бы было в пару строк уместиться.

Comment: @Akina моя цель - не написать готовый оптимизированный скрипт, а показать идею, как ни странно. Не понял, почему по 2 сообщения будет падать? джойн с макс датой - по дефолту 1 сообщение. Можно, конечно, брать id, но не факт, что в таблице не беспорядок.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Оконные функции ни к чему, когда надо получить значение одного поля по максимуму другого