# Выбрать значение по максимальной дате MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Предположим, есть большая таблица `test` со столбцами `credit_id`, `update_date` и `value`.

Необходимо выбрать `value` для каждого `credit_id`, соответствующий максимальной дате `update_date`.

В идеале, запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select m.credit_id, t.value
from (select credit_id, max(update_date) as mud
      from test
      group by credit_id) m
   join test t on m.credit_id = t.credit_id and m.mud = t.update_time
```

В Oracle был вариант с `keep dense_rank`, который упрощал задачу и позволял сделать без подзапроса. Есть какая-нибудь альтернатива в MySQL?

Comment: Если есть альтернатива вашему вопросу,ато так нет.

Comment: Альтернатива то почти всегда есть, но она вам не понравится :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/496532#496532  хотя у вас только одно поле вне группировки, второй вариант из того ответа в принципе подойдет, склейка, max, вырезка. С датой даже попроще, lpad будет не нужен, она фиксированной длины

Comment: И кстати, вы этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658939/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-sql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/658954#658954 ответ точно видели раньше, даже комент ваш там

Comment: @Mike точно, был тогда удивлен таким подходом. Эх, тогда придется остаться с подзапросом.