# Как получить ID моего друга?

Tags: sql

Как получить ID моего друга?

У меня есть такой Таблица **friends**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой уникальный ID **1**

1. Первый этап получаем список всех друзей

   `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friends.user_from = $id OR friends.user_to = $id;`

> Получаем 2, 4, 6

2. Второй этап получаем список всех друзей моего друга

   `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friends.user_from IN (SELECT friends.user_to FROM friends WHERE friends.user_from = $id) OR friends.user_to IN (SELECT friends.user_from FROM friends WHERE friends.user_to = $id);`

> Получаем 2 3, 4 7

3. Третий этап как узнать ID моего друга

> Полученный 2 или 3, 4 или 7

4. Четвертый этап должно быть так

   `echo $row['user_from']. ' '.$row['user_to']. '. Мой друг: '.$row['friend'];`
   `2 3. Мой друг: 2`
   `4 7. Мой друг: 4`

---

Comment: Ошибка настолько не понятна, что текст ошибки невозможно скопировать сюда ?

Comment: @Mike пожалуйста Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\friends.class.php:179 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(14): friends->all('1', 'news', '', 'true', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\friends.class.php on line 179

Comment: И кстати, что означает "передать в AS". `AS` это обозначение алиаса для поля, в него невозможно ничего передать. И `AS` в данном запросе нигде не нужно, хотя, конечно и мешать не должно

Comment: @Mike А как можно получить `friends.user_from` и `friends.user_to` в `IN()` в виде `friend`

Comment: Но в примененном вами тут коде нет вызова функции rowCount() на которой происходит ошибка. А сама ошибка говорит о том, что после отправки запроса в БД вы не убедились, что в запросе не было ошибок. А видимо они были. потому как вернулось false. Надо сделать проверку на false и поставить вывод ошибок БД (посмотрите пример в описаниях тех функций работы с БД, которые вы используете, там обычно присутствует и пример проверки на ошибки и вывода сообщений)

Comment: Я не понял, что вы хотите получить. В данный момент вы выводите все записи из таблицы friends по хитрым условиям. Что бы запрос вернул поле с именем friend надо что бы этот AS был в самом внешнем запросе, а не в подзапросах. Но в том виде как тут написано я не могу понять к какому полю надо применять этот самый AS. Подозреваю, что вам понадобится UNION, но болшего сказать опять же не могу не видя структуры БД, примера входных данных и примера того, что ожидается на выходе

Comment: @Mike пожалуйста извините, подождите я обновлю вопрос

Comment: Случайно не что то вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658939/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-sql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/658954#658954  (только без кучи ненужных полей, сумм и т.п.)

Comment: @Mike обновил вопрос

Comment: Постарайтесь в следующий раз давать исходные данные текстом (в идеале с create table и insert). больше половины времени ответа уходит на создание таблицы и перебивание данных с картинки...

Comment: @Mike Прошу прошение :) Спасибо большое за совет, все понятно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для MySQL:

```
select A.user_from, A.user_to, B.friend
  from friends A
  join (
        select if(user_from=1,user_to,user_from) as friend
          from friends
         where user_from=1 or user_to=1
       ) B
     on (A.user_from=B.friend or A.user_to=B.friend)
    and A.user_from!= 1 and A.user_to != 1
```

Для других СУБД, если они не поддерживают функцию `IF()` заменить ее на `case when user_from=1 then user_to else user_from end`.

Comment: спасибо вам большое!