# Нужно выбрать всех подписчиков пользователя в базе данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В базе данных есть таблица accounts - где хранятся все пользователи и есть таблица followers - где хранятся id подписчиков.Нужно сделать выборку всех подписчиков определенного пользователя.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
      id int PRIMARY KEY
    , about nvarchar(MAX)
    , name nvarchar(MAX)
    -- ...
);

CREATE TABLE followers (
      id int PRIMARY KEY
    , folower_id int
    , following_id int
    -- ...
 );
```

[image: Аккаунты]

[image: Подписчики]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/680503/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0/680536#680536 надеюсь сами упростите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM followers 
INNER JOIN accounts AS f ON f.id = followers.follower_id
INNER JOIN accounts AS f_ing ON f_ing.id = followers.following_id
WHERE f_ing.name = 'COMEDY CLAB';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3685e0/6)