# Составить SQL запрос с выбором значений по наибольшей дате

Tags: mysql, sql

Существует две таблицы

1. Группы **GRUP** ID | ID_USER
2. Сообщения **MSG** ID | ID_GRUP | TEXT | DATE

Как вывести все ID из таблицы GRUP по заданному ID_USER и к каждой полученной строке прикрутить последнее сообщение из таблицы MSG отсортированной по дате учитывая ID_GRUP записи?

Результат должен быть примерно такой:

```
Array(
'ID_GRUP' => 1, 'ID_USER' => 1, 'TEXT' => 'Текст сообщения 1', 'DATE' => '28-09-2017 9:27'
),
Array(
'ID_GRUP' => 2, 'ID_USER' => 2, 'TEXT' => 'Текст сообщения 2', 'DATE' => '28-09-2017 9:24'
)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658954/194569

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте.

```
SELECT * FROM GRUP AS G LEFT JOIN MSG AS M ON M.ID_GRUP = G.ID WHERE G.ID_USER = 1 ORDER BY M.DATE DESC LIMIT 1;
```