# Запрос ms sql количество

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица где хранятся сообщения пользователей:

id | id_from | id_to | date | text_msg | status

Т.е. кто, кому, дата, текст и статус

Статус по умолчанию null. Как только тот кому было предназначено сообщение прочитал его то в status пишется 1.

Задача:
Нужно вывести "диалоги", т.е. как типа в ВК - получить перечень диалогов где будет написано id_to (т.е. с кем диалог), последнее сообщение, и количество не прочитанных мной сообщении с каждым из пользователей.

Запрос MS SQL! Не MySQL

Уже 4 часа и ничего...

Спасибо!

```
USE [1gb_supchik]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[privatemessage](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[id_from] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
[id_to] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL,
[text_msg] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[status] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_privatemessage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[privatemessage]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
  [FK_privatemessage_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY([id_from])
  REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[privatemessage] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_privatemessage_AspNetUsers]
GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[privatemessage]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
 [FK_privatemessage_AspNetUsers1] FOREIGN KEY([id_to])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[privatemessage] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
 [FK_privatemessage_AspNetUsers1]
 GO
```

Comment: Вы же пробовали решить задачу - покажите запрос, который получился

Comment: select *,
(select count(*) from privatemessage left join privatemessage as fd on (privatemessage.id_to = fd.id_to and fd.status is null and fd.id_from = privatemessage.id_to)) 
from privatemessage 
where id_from='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653' or id_to='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653'

Comment: $first_query = mysql_query("select *, if(from_user=".$userdata['user_id'].",to_user,from_user) recipient,
       max(date) last_date,
       substr(max(concat(date,message)),20) last_msg,
       sum(status=0 and to_user=".$userdata['user_id'].") not_seen
  from messageprivate JOIN uc1 on (uc1.user_id= if(to_user=".$userdata['user_id'].",from_user,to_user))
 where (from_user=".$userdata['user_id']." or to_user=".$userdata['user_id'].")   
 group by recipient"); Вот запрос только для mysql... переделать не получается...

Comment: Отредактируйте сам вопрос, впишите в него чистый запрос SQL, без обрамления mysql_query. а то уже минусуют :(

Comment: select *, case  when id_from='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653' then id_to else id_from  recipient,
       max([date]) last_date,
       SUBSTRING(max(concat([date],text_msg)),20) last_msg,
       sum([status]= 0 and id_to='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653') not_seen
  from privatemessage 
 where (id_from='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653' or id_to='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653')   
 group by recipient

Comment: Я так понял вы основывались на этом MySQL варианте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658954/194569  в принципе оно должно боле менее работать, но я сильно сомневаюсь, что в MsSQL можно писать `sum([status]= 0 ...` скорее всего надо писать `sum(case when [status]= 0 ... then 1 else 0 end)` посмотрите (удалением полей из запроса) какие его части уже корректно работают а чего еще вызывает ошибки или не верный результат. Ну и * в самом начале точно все портит, потому что ее там не может быть при наличии group by

Comment: Да Mike как раз на вашем варианте и основывался...

Comment: как раз с группировкой не могу разобраться...

Comment: select id_from, id_to, text_msg, date, [status], (case  when id_from='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653' then id_to else id_from end ) as recipient,
       max([date]) last_date,
       SUBSTRING(max(concat([date],text_msg)),20, 20) last_msg,
    sum([status])     
 from privatemessage 
 where ((id_from='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653' or id_to='da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653')    )
 group by id_from,id_to,text_msg,date, [status]

Comment: ну в общем в таком виде его конечно можно довести до ума, только даты в строки наверняка по другому конвертятся и еще всякие нюансы. но в MS я бы пошел совсем другим путем. можете написать create table для создания этой таблицы с теми типами данных что у вас, я попробую сделать MS вариант с окнами

Comment: это последний вариант исправления последнего запроса, не могу понять почему нельзя сгруппировать по одному полю, например по id_from

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[privatemessage](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [id_from] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [id_to] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 [date] [datetime] NULL,
 [text_msg] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [status] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_privatemessage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: потому что MySQL единственная субд (ладно, еще sqlite) которая позволяет вольности с group by. для всех колонок которые не в group by но в select надо применять те или иные агрегатные функции. подробнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569  т.е. вам надо определиться что же вы для группы должны получить по таким полям, максимальное или минимальное значение

Comment: Добавил Create в вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66767/discussion-between--and-mike).

Comment: да ладно, я в курс въехал, сейчас попробую что то изобразить. я правильно понял, что вы его как и тот запрос выполнять будете для одного конкретного пользователя заданного в условиях ?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
  from (
     select recipient, text_msg, date,
            row_number() over(partition by recipient order by date desc) as RN,
            sum(1-to_me) over(partition by recipient) msg_count
       from (
         select *,
                case id_from when '2' then id_to else id_from end recipient,
                case id_to   when '2' then coalesce(cast(status as int),0) end to_me
           from privatemessage
          where id_from='2' or id_to='2'
       ) X
   ) Y
  where RN=1
```

В запросе `'2'` это пользователь для которого мы собираем данные.

Comment: не правильно считаем количество новых сообщений... выдает сколько уже прочитанных а не новых как я понял(((

Comment: ну это мелочи, поправил. правда я так и не понял зачем вы bit сделали NULL. Сделали бы его NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 было бы чуть удобнее. и NULL на from и to конечно странно выглядят, разве может быть сообщение никому или от никого

Comment: Афигеть! Работает! Огромное спасибо!!!!

Comment: Попробуйте еще RN=1 убрать и присмотреться к результату, что бы разобраться как именно оно работает :) Если что, row_number() нумерует записи в заданном порядке и первыми оказываются последние по дате